# How to stop gcloud docker -a overwriting long-lived credentials?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

We are using the Google Container Registry to store our Docker images.

To authorize our build instances we place **long-lived access tokens** in `.docker/config.json` as described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#using_a_json_key_file).

This works perfectly fine until someone (i.e. some Makefile) uses `gcloud docker -- push ...` to push to the registry (instead of e.g. `docker push ...`). `gcloud` will **replace the existing, long-lived credentials with short-lived ones** that expire after some time. Thus subsequent builds may fail, depending on the exact timing.

My **Question**: How can I prevent `gcloud docker ...` from messing with my provisioned credentials?

I've tried `chattr +i .docker/config.json`, but this just makes `gcloud` complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker:

> The gcloud docker command group wraps docker commands, so that gcloud can inject the appropriate fresh authentication token into requests that interact with the docker registry.

The only thing that `gcloud docker` does is change these credentials, then invoke the `docker` CLI. If you don't want it to change the credentials, there's no reason not to just call `docker` directly.

One workaround might be to use an alternate configuration file location for your long-lived credentials; per https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/:

```
Options:
      --config string      Location of client config files (default "/root/.docker")
```